# Passing a number via page arguments in hook_menu()

Tags: 7, routes

I am generating the return value for a hook_menu() with values from a query.

```
 $items[$record->path_prefix . '/my_path/%'] = array(
     'title' => 'Topic Redirect',
     'page callback' => 'my_callback',
     'page arguments' => array($record->id,2),
     'access callback' => TRUE,
     'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
   );
```

This will automatically pass the argument that is the record id to the callback function. I would like it to pass the value. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I normally just wrap the value in quotes, that should convince the router system to leave it alone:

```
'page arguments' => array("$record->id", 2)
```